# XSLT: Check if string contains any value from another group of nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```
  <table tableName="Groups">
    <item table="Groups">
      <column columnName="GroupID">GROUP1</column>
      <column columnName="GroupID">GROUP2</column>
    </item>
  </table>
  <table tableName="Products">
    <item table="Products">
      <column columnName="ProductID">1</column>
      <column columnName="ProductName">Product A</column>
      <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP1","GROUP2"</column>
    </item>
    <item table="EcomProducts">
      <column columnName="ProductID">2</column>
      <column columnName="ProductName">Product B</column>
      <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP3","GROUP4"</column>
    </item>
    <item table="EcomProducts">
      <column columnName="ProductID">3</column>
      <column columnName="ProductName">Product C</column>
      <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP1","GROUP3"</column>
    </item>
   </table>
```

I'm trying to filter out products that has any groups that are present in the Groups-table.
I would like to end up with this.

```
<products>
 <product>
  <name>Product A</name>
  <groups>"GROUP1","GROUP2"</groups>
 </product>
 <product>
  <name>Product C</name>
  <groups>"GROUP1","GROUP3"</groups>
 </product>
</products>
```

So far I have this XSLT, but as I'm pretty new to XSLT, I have no idea how to make that test-statement more dynamic:

```
<products>
    <xsl:for-each select="table[@tableName='Products']/item">
     <xsl:if test="contains(column[@columnName = 'Groups'] = 'GROUP1' and contains(column[@columnName = 'Groups'] = 'GROUP2'">
      <product>
       <name><xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName = 'ProductName']"/></name>
       <groups><xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName = 'Groups']"/></groups>
      </product>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</products>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor is that? Any support for string function to tokenize values like `"GROUP1","GROUP3"`?

Comment: The input you show is not well-formed XML: the root element is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="group-ids" select="table[@tableName='Groups']/item/column[@columnName='GroupID']" />
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="table[@tableName='Products']/item">
            <xsl:if test="$group-ids[contains(current()/column[@columnName='Groups'], concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;'))]">
                 <product>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='ProductName']"/>
                    </name>
                    <groups>
                        <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Groups']"/>
                    </groups>
                </product>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakB6

---

However, if your processor happens to support the EXSLT [str:tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension function, you could do something a bit simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp-id" match="table[@tableName='Groups']/item/column[@columnName='GroupID']" use="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;')" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="table[@tableName='Products']/item[key('grp-id', str:tokenize(column[@columnName='Groups'], ','))]">
            <product>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='ProductName']"/>
                </name>
                <groups>
                    <xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Groups']"/>
                </groups>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first example did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 1.0 solution, using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kContainsGroup" match="item[not(@table='Groups')]"
  use="boolean(
               /*/table[@tableName='Groups']/item/column
                             [contains(current()/column[@columnName='Groups'],
                                       concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;'))]
               )"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <products>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kContainsGroup', 'true')"/>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
   <product>
     <name><xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='ProductName']"/></name>
     <groups><xsl:value-of select="column[@columnName='Groups']"/></groups>
   </product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (fragment, made a well-formed XML document by enclosing it within a single top element `<tables>`):

```
<tables>
    <table tableName="Groups">
        <item table="Groups">
            <column columnName="GroupID">GROUP1</column>
            <column columnName="GroupID">GROUP2</column>
        </item>
    </table>
    <table tableName="Products">
        <item table="Products">
            <column columnName="ProductID">1</column>
            <column columnName="ProductName">Product A</column>
            <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP1","GROUP2"</column>
        </item>
        <item table="EcomProducts">
            <column columnName="ProductID">2</column>
            <column columnName="ProductName">Product B</column>
            <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP3","GROUP4"</column>
        </item>
        <item table="EcomProducts">
            <column columnName="ProductID">3</column>
            <column columnName="ProductName">Product C</column>
            <column columnName="Groups">"GROUP1","GROUP3"</column>
        </item>
    </table>
</tables>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<products>
   <product>
      <name>Product A</name>
      <groups>"GROUP1","GROUP2"</groups>
   </product>
   <product>
      <name>Product C</name>
      <groups>"GROUP1","GROUP3"</groups>
   </product>
</products>
```

**Do note**:

1. No XSLT conditional instruction (such as `<xsl:if>`) has been used.
2. No `<xsl:for-each>` instruction has been used
3. The solution is implemented in almost pure "push-style"